# bash if statement never enters else clause

Tags: bash

I've created a bash script, but it's not working like I desired. It should check, if a folder exists. If the folder doesn't exists, it should create a directory, or print out the message `folder is exist already`, if it exists.

But now the problem is, if the folder is already there, the statement is not going into the else part, so it's not printing out anything.

```
var={FolderName}
      if [ ! -d $var ]
      then
       mkdir -p "{Destination}/{FolderName}"
      else
       echo folder is exist already
      fi
```

Comment: It seems you are checking in one folder and creating in another

Comment: working fine.thank you

Comment: The whole point of the `-p` option is that you don't need to check if the directory exists before you try to create it. If it exists, then `mkdir` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `$` to your code.

```
var=${FolderName}
      if [ ! -d $var ]
      then
       mkdir -p "${Destination}/${FolderName}"
      else
       echo folder is exist already
      fi
```